# setting DirectX9 surface pixels

Tags: c++, directx, set, pixel, surface

I'm trying to set the individual pixels in a D3DSURFACE9 but they're going all over the place.
I think I've done this before but can't seem to get it right this time.

```
3DLOCKED_RECT lrt;
if(D3D_OK == lpThis->sfRenderingCanvas->LockRect(&lrt,NULL,0))
{
   UINT pitch = lrt.Pitch;
   VOID *data;
   data = lrt.pBits;
   UINT Y = (UINT)xmsg.Y;
   UINT X = (UINT)xmsg.X;
   for(int z=0;xmsg.iNum;z++)
   {
      if( xmsg.iDataBlock[z]>0 )
         ((DWORD*)data)[X+Y*pitch+z] = 0xFFFFFF00;
      else
         ((DWORD*)data)[X+Y*pitch+z] = 0xFF000000;
      }
   }
}
```

*Y is between 0 and the height used when creating the surface

X is between 0 and the pitch of the surface*

Can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong?
Also, it seems to go about twice as far down as my window.
(^If I try to draw over 1/4 the rows, it covers 1/2 of them.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use the {}-Code Button to format source code rather than HTML tags. Apart from that, you can use Markdown syntax.

Comment: maybe it's my browser but I've always had bad luck with those tags. it doesn't usually format my first line and this time it seemed to disapear when I put my code in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pitch value that comes back in the [D3DLOCKED_RECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the number of bytes between the start of each row, not the number of DWORDs.  You're indexing into the buffer using a DWORD pointer, so you are effectively using a pitch four times too large.

Try something like this...

```
DWORD * row = (DWORD *)((char *)lrt.pBits + pitch * Y);
for(int z=0;xmsg.iNum;z++)
{
   if( xmsg.iDataBlock[z]>0 )
      row[X+z] = 0xFFFFFF00;
   else
      row[X+z] = 0xFF000000;
   }
}
```

Comment: I got the addressing to work with ((DWORD*)(((BYTE*)data)+Y*pitch))[X+z] but have to set the width for the x values to pitch/4.. Shouldn't it be X/8??? (that doesn't work)

Comment: Why is X "between 0 and the pitch"?  The pitch value may be any arbitrary value larger than the width * pixel size (though in practice it will be a multiple of 4).  There will often be padding in between each row and the pitch accounts for that.  You shouldn't be trying to do anything with that padding space.  X and Y should only be in the range of your logical texture coordinates.  i.e. width and height.